# return empty session when using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with this code. I am trying to pass an input value to use it in another page using session but it returns nothing. I am using ajax to prevent page reload. the contents of the table are the seminars' details from the database and each button handle the seminar_id. the code is

c.php

```
<?php
   session_start();
?>                 
<div class="container">
<table class="semin">               
  <tr>                               
    <th>TITLE</th>
    <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
    <th>DATE</th>
    <th>START TIME</th>
    <th>END TIME</th>
    <th>AVAILABILITY</th>
    <th>BOOKING</th>                                
</tr>                   
 <?php     
  if(isset($_POST["ID"]))
   {
     $_SESSION["id"]=$_POST["sid"];
    }                       
      $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","test","test","test");
      $a= "select * from SEMINAR1 where DATE >= CURDATE() and VACANCY > 0";
        $result = $con->query($a);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0)
        {
          // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['TITLE']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['DESCRIPTION']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['DATE']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['START_TIME']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['END_TIME']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['VACANCY']?></td>
                    <td>   
                     <form class="regist" method="post" >
  <input type="submit" value="register" name="ID" class="reg1"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="sid" name="do" value="<?php echo $row['ID'];?>"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="vac" value="<?php echo $row['VACANCY'];?>"/>
                     </form>
                    </td>                                                                            
            <?php
            }
        }                           
    ?> 
 </table>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $('form.regist').on('submit', function(){
            $('#content').load('a.php');
            return false;
            });
            </script>
 </div>
```

and the page that I am using to print the session is 
a.php

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $val=$_SESSION["id"];
   echo $val;
?>
```

Comment: sorry, it is sid not sem_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I think it should be `$_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['do']`. **$_POST['sid'] doesn't exist**, you have id="sid" and name="do" on that DOM element.

Also as I can see you don't submit your form via ajax (but I'm sorry if other part of your code does this, I just want to be sure to help you out).

```js
$('form.regist').on('submit', function(){
    $('#content').load('a.php');
    return false;
});
```

This code actually stops the form being submitted and loads a.php content.

Try this code and see if it works:

```js
$('form.regist').on('submit', function() {
    // preventing form submission
    e.preventDefault();
    // getting form data
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    // sending form data via ajax post
    $.post('url', data, function() {
        // after request completed loading a.php content
        $('#content').load('a.php');
    });
});
```

Hope I helped. :)

Comment: i have got this error (Notice: Undefined index: sid in C:\wamp\www\test\c.php on line 18)

Comment: Sorry, I edited my answer, you don't have $_POST['sid'], you have $_POST['do'], correct the name attribute on that hidden input to 'sid' and it'll be fine. :)

Comment: It loads a.php but it is empty!

Comment: It should work. Please write var_dump($_SESSION); into a.php and check if it's empty.

Comment: this is the output :   array (size=2)
  'ID' => null
  'id' => null

Comment: now, the session handles fixed value(1) for all seminars.as a result, the output is 1 .

Comment: So it works? By the way your code runs, because 'id' key is set, but it doesn't have value. Did you fixed the $_POST['do'] part?

Comment: it has value but the value is the same each time i click a button!

Comment: Do hidden input fields have the same value? Remove id="sid" from input element because you have it multiple times, and id must be unique.

Comment: it has different values and it still brings the same value after removing id

Comment: Sorry, it's my bad, instead of $('form').serialize() use $(this).serialize(). I updated my answer.

Comment: Still the same.what i have just noticed that if I change the index of a session to another index name like ($_SESSION["find"]), I get an error saying the undefined index (find) in a.php

Comment: Yes, because I'm pretty sure you don't define $_SESSION['find'] anywhere. Also $_SESSION['id'] is not session id. You can find your session id by calling ```echo session_id();```. You should check what data goes with your ajax request and debug that. I think it doesn't matter which button you click on, it always sends first form's data. Please mark my answer accepted, because your session isn't empty now, and that was the original question. I can't help you out with this, because I can't test your code. Thank you. :)

Comment: thanks a lot. unfortunately, it seems that I can not vote because I do not have enough reputation.